# How do I extract data as strings from Google Sheets column?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I'm in the process of learning the Google Sheets API with Python. I'm trying to extract data from a column in the spreadsheet, but it extracts it as a list of lists. For example, if the list contains the following names in Column A of the spreadsheet.

```
Alexandra
Andrew
Anna
Becky
Benjamin
```

I started off by importing the `gspread` library and initial variables, then grabbed the entire column, stored it into a variable, and printed.

```
import gspread

sa = gspread.service_account()
sh = sa.open("gSheets-Python")
wks = sh.worksheet("Class Data")

sheetsColA = wks.get('A2:A')
print(sheetsCol)
```

This yielded the following console output.

```
[['Alexandra'], ['Andrew'], ['Anna'], ['Becky'], ['Benjamin']]
```

Suppose that I want to store the 3rd entry from this list ("Anna"), so I ran `print(sheetsCol[2])`, which yielded `['Anna']`. In another example, I noticed that they ran `print(wks.acell(A4).value)` which yielded `Anna`, without the brackets.

Attempting to do the same on the `get` function, I get an error. I ran `print(sheetsCol[2].value)`, hoping to get `Anna`, but instead got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("sheetsCol[2] = ", sheetsCol[2].value, "\n")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'
```

How do I get `Anna` as just a string in a variable, instead of `['Anna']`? Does it need to be in the `['Anna']` format if I want to use the code to paste it back into the sheet in a different location? Like if I want to move or copy `Anna` to the D4 cell.

The long-term goal is to grab data from a column, and process them one-by-one for web scraping with BeautifulSoup4, then paste the web-scraped results in another column in the sheet. The web scraping is for another discussion, but is this the correct overall approach?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Just use starred expression to unpack list `print(*["txt"])`
2. Use for loop to run through values.
3. Use list indexes to get value  `var = lst[0]`

---

The error occurs because: sheetsCol[2] is a list, I may suppose that it is the list of wks.acell objects, therefore u can go through it and acquire all values.
Example:

```
for i in sheetsCol[n]:
    print(i.value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to unpack using `*sheetsCol[i]` and list out all items in Column A without the brackets. Next, I tried to unpack into a variable in case I plan to use it again. I tried `name = *sheetsCol[i]`, but got an error saying that I can't use the starred expression in a variable declaration. How do I properly unpack into a variable so that the string can be used elsewhere?

Comment: Another solution: say you have array with one element and you want to unpack it. 
`l = [1]` you can do it just like this `var = l[0]`